# what type of integer to use to represent a 19 digit number

Tags: c

I am having a problem with my code.
I have to do a calculation, but when a specific number becomes to big it doesn't print the right answer, I am now using the type `int`. but I don't know if that is the best choice.

This is my code:

```
int faculty(int faculty1)
{

    printf("enter faculty\n");
    scanf("%i", &faculty1); //faculty1 is a number from 1 to 20
    int i;
    int fact = 1;

    for(i=1; i<=faculty1; i++)
    {
         fact *= i;
    }

    return (fact);
}
```

Which type can I use to avoid overflow in the faculty calculation?

Comment: The size of each data type is listed in the documentation for those types.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with both `c` and `c#`? It can't be both, and it looks like you're only looking for `c`. But `int` won't work in any of those cases...

Comment: You'll need unsigned 64-bit to hold 19 decimal digits.

Comment: Are you *really* trying to calculate the factorial of a 19-digit number? You know how fast a factorial grows, right? Can an `unsigned long long` hold that value?

Comment: Folks, please read the code carefully and look at what it is trying to do, before suggesting the use of an `unsigned long long` or similarly sized variable. Not only is that answer wrong (the bug is elsewhere), that answer completely ignores what goes on in the rest of the function!

Comment: sorry i am totally new in this, i meant c indeed. the meaning is to calculate the faculty till 20, so i doenst keeps going on. i just tried long long and it worked. so everyone thanks for responding to the question!

Comment: The factorial of 20 will fit comfortably in 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably want to use the `unsigned long long` for storing values which are 19 digits long.

The maximum value is 18446744073709551615 (2^64-1) or greater*

Also beware that the format specifier for that is `%llu`

Also

```
scanf("%i", &faculty1);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &faculty1);
```

and if faculty1 is the one which contains the 19 digit number then

```
scanf("%llu", &faculty1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `uintmax_t`, defined in `stdint.h` which is guaranteed to be the largest unsigned type on a platform. Plus, you could check how many digits it offers through `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(uintmax_t) * log10(2.0)`

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be wrong:

```
scanf("%i", &faculty1); //faculty1 is a number from 1 to 20
```

You want to use `%d`, not `%i` — assuming that `faculty1` is an integer from 1 to 20, and you want to calculate the factorial of that integer.

I'm assuming that you can't possibly intend to calculate the factorial of a 19-digit number.

Even using an `unsigned long long`, you'll [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) at some point much, much sooner than your 19-digit value.

Please clarify your question and what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of types that you can use when you need 64 bits:

- `long long` is guaranteed by the standard to be at least 64 bits.
- Any of appropriate types defined in `stdint.h`. They take the form `int64_t`, `fast64_t`, `least64_t`, etc. `int64_t` is, of course, exactly 64 bit wide, the other two are guaranteed to have at least 64 bits.

For all of these types, there are also unsigned variants (`unsigned long long`, or `uint64_t` etc.). Just choose the one you like best.

Answer (score 0):

OP clearly states he wants the factorial of up to 20. You can do this with 64-bit int.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long fact=1;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=20; i++) {
        fact *= i;
        printf("%2d! = %lld\n", i, fact);   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
 1! = 1
 2! = 2
 3! = 6
 4! = 24
 5! = 120
 6! = 720
 7! = 5040
 8! = 40320
 9! = 362880
10! = 3628800
11! = 39916800
12! = 479001600
13! = 6227020800
14! = 87178291200
15! = 1307674368000
16! = 20922789888000
17! = 355687428096000
18! = 6402373705728000
19! = 121645100408832000
20! = 2432902008176640000
```